# Big size difference between apt-get install and binary file of apache Maven

Tags: apt, maven-3

I am installing Apache Maven onto my Ubuntu 12.04; and `sudo apt-get install maven`  gives me 229 MB of file to download. On the other hand, going to Apache Maven site, I can download a 7 MB file. What could be the reason behind this?

[image: A screenshot of the offer I am getting from apt-get]

Comment: Could you post a link to that file you want to download? Maybe it is just an downloader/installer, that downloads and installs the program when you launch it (and gets the remaining 229MB then). Are you sure you got the Ubuntu version and nothing for Windows too?

Comment: Did you also add Java to the download size of 7MB?

Comment: @muru No, I have downloaded and configured Oracle JDK. I only need to install Maven.

Comment: @ByteCommander the site is <maven.apache.org/dowload.cgi> there is no installer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are conflating three things:

- the size of Maven itself
- the size of Maven + all its dependencies, like Java
- the size of the compressed packages (vs its actual size).

The size of the Maven package is only about 1.3 MB because of compression (see `apt-cache show maven | grep -i size`). The total size of the packages you are installing is 139 MB (compressed, which is what you'll download) - 229 MB after unpacking. This includes the OpenJDK 6 JDK.

Since you have already installed Oracle JDK, it might be best for you to manually install Maven, instead of using `apt`, since you'll have to download the OpenJDK version as well if you use `apt`.

If you want to be fair, add the size of the Oracle JDK (around 135 MB) to that 7 MB, which should tell you it's around the same size as well.

Comment: Thanks, I thought apt-get should have asked me if I needed the dependencies like JDK, which I already have.

Comment: @Andromeda `apt` cannot ask, it since what happens outside of packages is none of its business.

Comment: is that what they call a stub installer?

Comment: @j0h the maven package? I doubt it. I didn't want to install Java, so I didn't actually install it.